# html iframe:How to put iframe for the below code

Tags: html, iframe

I need to include iframe for my html code below.How to do this?Following is my code:

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
      <body>
         <table>
    <tr>
         <% dim CountFlg
                CountFlg = 0
                for i=0 to XmlNodes.length-1
                    if CountFlg <= 2 then %>
                        <td class="style3" >
                            <span class="style4">
                                <b><%=XmlNodes.item(i).getAttribute("Name")%></b>
                            </span>&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <TD>
                            <input class="TextArea" name="<% i % >" id="<% i %>" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10"> </input>
                        </TD>
                        <% CountFlg=CountFlg+1
                    end if
                next%>
            </tr>
           </table>
         </body>
        </html>
```

I have skipped my rest of the code here.Is there a way to include only tr tag in iframe?I tried adding iframe here tat didn`t work.I don`t have a separate file for the html content,i`m building this html in classic asp file.So suggest some answers please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

An `iframe` isn't allowed anywhere a `tr` is, and the root element of an HTML document must be `html` not `tr` so you can't have an HTML document that starts with a `tr`.

Comment: :You mean to say I have to include complete html tag inside iframe right?If yes,is it enough if I just add iframe tag at the beggining?

Comment: I don't see how that would help with your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The html code for iframe is...

```
<iframe class="IFrameClass" src="" ></iframe>
```

In src u can include that path of any html file or what ever you need.

For more details visit [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools, their information is shoddy at best and teaches how to write code with huge security holes at worst.

Comment: @Quentin:Yeah I know that it is mandatory,i `ll include tat.My question was is it enough if i just add iframe tag before my html tag?I`m building this html inside a classic asp file,inside script tag,that`s why i`m asking you.I don`t have separate html file for this.

Comment: You have to have a separate HTML document (or other resource) to use an iframe. The point of an iframe is to load external content into a document.

Comment: @Quentin:Alright I got it wat you said.But I don`t know how to separate my html to a different file now.

Comment: @Quentin:Oh sorry i forgot to include the end tag...See my edit now.
I thought W3Schools provide best tutorials for beginners. That's why i recommended it.

Comment: @user1495475: you can declare the iframe in your html code with empty src and set the src dynamically using jquery as    $(".IFrameClass").attr("src", PathOfExternalHTML);
The external file will only contain the content you want to show in IFrame, so you can easily create one.